# No network connection when hanging up a call

Tags: mobile-network, lineageos

Whenever I end a call the system becomes sluggish and non interactive for a brief moment, then I get the message "No network connection", and the call ends.

This happens every time.

- Software: Android 7.1.1, Resurrection Remix Nougat, RR-N-v5.8.2-20170218-n7100-Milestone, kernel: 3.0.101-lineage-gf497f6e
- Hardware: Samsung Galaxy Note 2, n7100.

I've just moved from Cyanogenmod, I did not have this problem before. I've had the problem ever since installing RR.

Perhaps unrelated, but every time the power button is pressed there is a few seconds delay before the screen actually turns on. This also was not a problem before, not with Cyanogenmod, not with the stock Android that came with the device.

What is the cause of this/these issues?